# CTE Incorrect Syntax near ')'

Tags: sql-server, subquery, common-table-expression

I'm coming from a PostgreSQL background, where the following query would be totally fine:

```
;with abc (a) as (
    select
        a
    from DB.dbo.mytable 
)   

select
    a
from abc;
```

But SQL Server doesn't seem to like the fact that I have subqueried the table. I've tried several versions of this including subquery, CTE, with and without the (a).
What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: The code works fine. What error do you get?

Comment: Discovered the problem was due to my IDE and highlighting.

Comment: The semicolon is a statement TERMINATOR in TSql. It is not a beginator. Stop trying to compensate for lazy coding by adding it as the first character in a script. 3-part names are also a bad habit - don't do that without a very good reason.

Answer (score -1):

I discovered this was actually an issue in my IDE that requires the SQL being executed to be entirely highlighted. Can't have an unhighlighted or partial highlight or it will fail.